# Close child window when parent window closes using cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a timeout page for my parent window. But it doesn’t close the child window. I created a cookie to store the idle time in JavaScript. It still doesn’t close the child window.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: I have used a timeout for an idle session in my parent window. I’m trying to use cookies to set the idle time across all the open windows. This is the code that I have used; idletime=0; which increments after one minute. Cookie cookie=new Cookie(“idle”,idletime); response.addCookie(cookie); I’m new to cookies and I’m trying to find a way to close the pop ups from the parent window once it closes.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [open()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) method. It will return a handle to your new window. That way you can keep a record of all your pop-ups in your main window an close them again with [close()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp).

Comment: Please provide the full javascript you're using, both the main page and popup window... Otherwise we can only guess.